# Are there any summer minyanim in Banff or Jasper, AB?

Tags: synagogue, travel, minyan

I've hunted the web on this. I know that Edmonton is closest to Jasper and Calgary is closest to Banff, and each have sizable Jewish communities (not sure which if these 2 cities is larger in terms of Orthodox shuls and kosher places).

I'm looking more specifically if there are any minyanim in or near either of these provincial parks. Perhaps, one of the hotels tends to have one? Would someone know? Where are they?

Comment: Search at godaven.com

Comment: You planning on going up to the 51st state this summer?

Comment: I looked on godaven.com. There were no results for Banff or Jasper, and the Calgary and Edmonton pages only showed minyaim inside of the cities.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Possibly. Perhaps just behind Alaska, Banff is my dream destination. All the pictures that I have seen of the place are breath-taking.